# Искажение данных JS

Tags: php, javascript

В начале страницы написано

```
var next = "76561198084473205"
```

Но, когда прописываешь `console.log(next);`
Выдает `76561198084473200`
Никаких изменений не происходит в процессе кода
С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Можно ваш код пожалуйста.

Comment: Приведу пример из PHP
<script>console.log(<? $next = "76561198084473205"; echo $next; ?>);</script> 
Выдается такое же искаженное число

Comment: Число слишком большое и выходит за пределы точности чисел в javascript

Comment: Оно точно написано именно вот так, с кавычками? Очень странно, если так.

Comment: @Yaant ничего странного. После вывода в код JS данная последовательность цифр станет числовым литералом

Comment: Совет, который не совсем касается сути вопроса: не выводите значения в JS код. Передавайте их через значения и атрибуты HTML. Например в data атрибут можно положить даже массив или сложный объект в JSON и потом доставать его оттуда средствами JS

Comment: @tutankhamun мне [совсем недавно доказывали](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76286), что так делать плохо :)

Comment: @andreymal Черт побери, где я был, почему не поучаствовал :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Число выходит за пределы точности чисел в `JavaScript`. Смотрите [ответ на английском StackOverflow про это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/9801830).

Если вам нужно работать с такими числами, то пользуйтесь библиотекой [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) или [Big Number](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber).

Comment: Если автор ничего не напутал в вопросе, то у него в переменной не число, а строка. И тогда точность тут не причём.

Comment: @Yaant в комментарии автор привёл другой вариант кода, на который точность уже влияет

Comment: @Yaant, он неправильно скопировал из `PHP` и поэтому выглядит как строка, но при выводе через `PHP` кавычки не выводятся и там уже будет не строка.

Comment: Ну, видимо, да. Просто я тоже уже было принялся писать комментарий про `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, но вдруг обратил внимание на кавычки, и засомневался. :)