# Почему один код на php и js считает по разному?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть php код для генерации последовательности чисел:

```
$seed = 100;
$seed = (1103515245 * $seed  + 12345) % (1 << 31);
dump($seed);
$seed = (1103515245 * $seed  + 12345) % (1 << 31);
dump($seed);
```

Он сгенерирует два числа:

```
829870797
1533044610
```

Этот же код переписанный на javascript:

```
    var seed = 100;
    seed = (1103515245 * seed  + 12345) % (1 << 31);
    console.log(seed); 
    seed = (1103515245 * seed  + 12345) % (1 << 31);
    console.log(seed);
```

Сгенерирует это:

```
829870797
1533044608
```

**Почему второе число в js отличается и как это оба варианта привести к общему виду?**

Comment: Потому что в JS `1103515245 * 829870797 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`. Другими словами, происходит потеря точности.

Comment: Спасибо. Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Ну, видимо, придется использовать длинную арифметику. Либо найти какую-нибудь библиотеку, либо написать самому, это не так уж и сложно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Искажение данных JS](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/830361/%d0%98%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оба вывода (и в `PHP` и в `JavaScript`) неправильны. С `PHP` здесь тоже самое, что и с `JavaScript`, описанное мной ниже.

Число `(1103515245 * 829870797)` выходит за пределы точности чисел в `JavaScript`. Смотрите [ответ на английском StackOverflow про это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307200/9801830).

Если вам в `JavaScript` нужно работать с такими числами, то пользуйтесь библиотекой [BigInteger.js](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js) или [Big Number](http://jsfromhell.com/classes/bignumber).